# Sending Email from asp classic page

Tags: asp-classic

When @ is in the body of email of classic asp page , the server where my application is deployed is not sending email. When I remove @ from the body email are going . Please tell me what could be the issue.

Thanks 
Irfan Shaikh

Comment: special character error in the body of mail

Answer (score 0):

Without more information such as code examples and server stack etc, I would say maybe replace the character with `& #64;`